# Changing a Value in a field using VBA in MS Project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I'm using `Text1` field with lookup values in it and based on a specific value from that I want then update the field "Marked" to equal "Yes"

`Text1` values
- On Target
- Delayed

I've tried using formulas within Custom Fields

`IIf([Text1]="On Target",[Marked]="True",[Marked]="False")`

I'm actually trying to Conditionally format the row when `Text1 = Delayed`. One reason why I want to do this is to use a field such as [Marked] that is rarely used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vba procedure that will set the `Marked` field depending on the value of the `Text1` field.

```
Sub SetMarked()
    Dim tsk As Task
    For Each tsk In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If Not tsk Is Nothing Then
            tsk.Marked = (tsk.Text1 = "On Target")
        End If
    Next tsk
End Sub
```

FYI: The `Flag1-10` fields can be customized with a formula to do the same thing: `IIf([Text1]="On Target",True,False)`. The flag fields can be used to customize the Gantt bars, but not the text in the Gantt table (like the `Marked` field can).

Comment: Glad this works for you. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)